# Force php reading into an embed iframe field in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, iframe, shortcode

In my old Wordpress theme I've a special function that allow to insert a YouTube video with iFrame in the right side of Portofolio Posts.
But now I've to insert into this place (for each portfolio posts) a simple shortcode (different for each portfolio post) for a web audio player like this `[disk_player id="2513"]` .

This code cannot be read and it results as a simple line of text. Also the equivalent php code for the shortcode cannot be read (like this  `<?php echo do_shortcode('[disk_player id="2513"]'); ?>`.

I've also tried to add `[raw] ... [/raw]` tags before and after code but it doesn't work.

Can you help me to force the reading of the shortcode in this field?

Big thanks to everyone.
P

Comment: Could you give more infos on the special function you mentioned or which theme you're using?

Answer (score 0):

This is the code of right column:

```
    <li id="right-column">
            <div class="gallery-slider clearfix">

                <?php if(obox_has_video($post->ID)):
                    $args  = array('postid' => $post->ID, 'width' => 660, 'height' => 660, 'hide_href' => true, 'exclude_video' => false, 'imglink' => false, 'wrap' => 'div', 'wrap_class' => 'post-image fitvid');
                    $image = get_obox_media($args);
                    echo $image;
                else : ?>
                    <ul class="gallery-container">
                        <?php $attach_args = array("post_type" => "attachment", "post_parent" => $post->ID, "numberposts" => "-1", "orderby" => "menu_order", "order" => "ASC");
                        $attachments = get_posts($attach_args);
                        foreach($attachments as $attachement => $this_attachment) :  
                            $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src($this_attachment->ID, "660auto");
                            $full = wp_get_attachment_image_src($this_attachment->ID,  "full"); ?>
                            <li>
                                <a href="<?php echo $full[0]; ?>" rel="lightbox">
                                    <img src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" alt="<?php echo $this_attachment->post_title; ?>" />
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </ul>
                    <?php if(count($attachments) > 1) : ?>
                        <div class="controls"> 
                            <a href="#" class="next"><?php _e("Next", "ocmx") ?></a> 
                            <a href="#" class="previous"><?php _e("Previous", "ocmx") ?></a>
                        </div> 
                    <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
        </li>
```

And the theme is the 1st version of this: http://demo.oboxsites.com/retail-therapy/ (really different from mine).

Thank you